# Questions about representation theory of associative algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC).

I have two questions on page 85. On Line 18 of Page 85, it is said that $\ker p_i \subseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i$. I know that if $\ker p_i \subseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i$, then $\ker p_i$ is superfluous. Since the sequence in the proof is a minimal projective resolution of $S$, $\ker p_i$ is superfluous. How to show that if $\ker p_i$ is superfluous, then we have $\ker p_i \subseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i$?

On Line -6 of Page 85, it is said that $$ \hom _A(\operatorname{rad} P(a)/ \operatorname{rad}^2 P(a), S(b)) \cong  \hom _A(\operatorname{rad} P(a)/ \operatorname{rad}^2 P(a), I(b)). \quad (1) $$ It seems that we do not have $S(b) \cong I(b)$, how to show that (1) is true? Thank you very much. I attached Page 85 of the book. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) The first statement can be proven by contradiction. The important fact for your first question is that the indecomposable projectives have a simple top. Thus, let $P_i:=\oplus_j P_i^j$, where $P_i^j$ is an indecomposable module. Suppose $\operatorname{ker}p_i\nsubseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i$. Then, since $\operatorname{rad} P_i^j$ is the unique maximal submodule of $P_i^j$ there exists at least one $j$ such that $P_i^j\subseteq \operatorname{ker} p_i$. But now $\ker p_i+\oplus_{k\neq j} P_i^k=P_i$ and the second summand is a proper submodule. Hence $\ker p_i$ is not superfluous.

(2) Here the important fact is that $\operatorname{rad} P(a)/\operatorname{rad}^2 P(a)$ is a semisimple module. Because of the fact that $\operatorname{Hom}(M,-)$ is left exact it holds that $\operatorname{Hom}(M,S(b))\hookrightarrow  \operatorname{Hom}(M,I(b))$ for any module $M$. But now since $\operatorname{rad} P(a)/\operatorname{rad}^2 P(a)$ is semisimple we know that $\operatorname{soc} ( \operatorname{rad} P(a)/\operatorname{rad}^2 P(a) )=\operatorname{rad} P(a)/\operatorname{rad}^2 P(a)$. And we know that $f(\operatorname{soc} M)\subseteq \operatorname{soc} N$ for any morphism $M\to N$. In this special case we can deduce $f(\operatorname{rad} P(a)/\operatorname{rad}^2 P(a))\subseteq \operatorname{soc} I(b)=S(b)$ and thus the map is also surjective.

Comment: thank you very much. Could we conclude that $\operatorname{rad} P_i = \oplus_j \operatorname{rad} P_i^{j}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $P_i$? If this is true, then $\ker p_i \subseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i$ since $\ker p_i$ is an ideal. I don't understand that why there is one $j$ such that $P_i^j \subseteq \ker p_i$.

Comment: No, the direct sum has several maximal ideals: take one $\operatorname{rad} P_i^j$ and all other $P_i^k$ these are the maximal ideals.

Comment: but each $P_i^k$ is not an ideal. Could we conclude that the direct sum of $\operatorname{rad} P_i^j$ and other $P_i^k$ is an maximal ideal?

Comment: I have some difficulty in understanding $P_i^j \subseteq \ker p_i$ for some $j$. Suppose that $P_i$ is indecomposable. We assume that $\ker p_i \not\subseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i$. Then by your argument, since $\operatorname{rad} P_i = \operatorname{rad} P_i^j$ is the unique maximal ideal of $P_i=P_i^j$, we have $P_i=P_i^j\subseteq \ker p_i$. But now we have $\ker p_i = P_i$.

Comment: I understand this question now. Suppose that $\ker p_i \not\subseteq \operatorname{rad} P_i = \oplus_j \operatorname{rad} P_i^j$. Then there is some $j$ and $x \in \ker p_i$ such that $x \in P_i \backslash \operatorname{rad} P_i^j$. Therefore $P_i^j$ equals the submodule generated by $\{x\} \cup \operatorname{rad} P_i^j$. Since $x \in \ker p_i$ and $\ker p_i$ is an ideal, we have the submodule generated by $\{x\} \cup \operatorname{rad} P_i^j$ is contained in $\ker p_i$. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, and hence $\operatorname{ker} p_i$ cannot be superfluous. Sorry about the confusion about the ideals, it should always be submodule instead of ideal.

Comment: @LJR  Can you explain to me why $rad P_i^j$ is contained in $ker p_i$ as the sentence "we have the submodule generated by $\{x\}∪rad P_i^j$ is contained in $ker p_i$" showed ?